# XSD validation error: cos-element-consistent: element is not consistent with element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have problem with XML Schema application. First case was with one sequence with element referencing. This case works, but I have a request, which allow one element `onlyone` in `main` element or `onlyone` in element `problem` (not in `main` element). I tried many solutions especially splitting to sequence and making element `problem` referencing as new defined element. This works, but when I add `complexType` into element `problem`, it will warn me as error. I need there new element `problem` with requested condition.

**XSD:**

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="el1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="el2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="problem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="inside1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="inside2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="onlyone" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="el3" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="el1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="el2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="problem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="inside1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="onlyone" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="inside2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="el3" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:sequence>
```

And XMLSpy writes me, when saving:

> Element 'problem' is not consistent with element 'problem' a cos-element-consistent.1: Both type definitions ('{anonymous}' and '{anonymous}') must be named.

Answer (score 0):

XSD has an [**Element Declarations Consistent**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-element-consistent)  constraint that requires that same named elements within a content model have consistent content models.  Your `problem` element violates this constraint by having two different content models within the same superior content model and is thus, indeed, a problem.

Resolution can take one of the following forms:

1. Rename one of the `problem` elements.
2. Make the content models of the two `problem` elements consistent
   (and, better, commonly referenced (via `xs:element/@ref`).
3. Remove the sibling relationship between the two inconsistent `problem` content models.